# Finite Differences Method

Tags: finite-differences

I am confused when following the instructions where i have gone wrong and why its not coming out right when considering a first order ODE

$ y′(x) = y(x), \quad \forall x ∈ [0, 1] $

$ y(0) = 1.$

I am trying to prove $ y_i = (1+h)^i $ for $ i=0, ... , n $ where $h=1/n$.So far i have done the following [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UZVC.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  $y_{i+1}=y_i(1+h)$ as you have shown.  So $y_{1}=y_0(1+h)$, $y_{2}=y_1(1+h)=y_0(1+h)^2$ etc.  Applying your relation again and again in this way, you get $y_{i}=y_0(1+h)^i$.